# using same component with different state as child in multiple components angular 6/7

Tags: angular, components, angular6, angular-components, angular7

[image]

I have one ErrorComponent which i am adding in two of my component. 1 is parent and other is its child. issue is errorcomponent in both component taking same instance. so whenever i want to display error only in parent component it also getting displayed on child component and vice versa.

i want to keep both errorcomponent as different instance. please help. thanks in advance.

you can play with the code here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-21woxg?file=src%2Findex.html

Comment: Please add some sample code to work with. It would be great if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You can use [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) to create one.

Comment: @SiddAjmera here you go https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-21woxg?file=src%2Findex.html

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to provide things that you want them to be dynamic to your component as an input then in you'll be able to have different state for your Error component for example if you want to customize the error message in your `error-component.ts` you add:

```
export class ErrorComponent  {
  @Input()ErrorMessage='default error'
}
```

Then in your `parent-component.html`

```
<my-error-component [ErrorMessage]="http failure .."> </my-error-component>
```

and in your `child-component.html`

```
<my-error-component [ErrorMessage]="No internet connection .."> </my-error-component>
```

Comment: error messages should be added from HttpInterceptor and i dont want to write messages at each and every component level as per your suggestion.

Comment: Your current implementation does not provide the flexibility to display different error messages in each error component your `Error component` is subscribing directly on your `notify service` which  will emit each time the httpInterceptor intercepts an error this way all the HTTP errors would directly be displayed in your error component

Answer (score 0):

It won't be possible with the sort of implementation that you have as of now. The reason being, you have the `ErrorComponent` used in the templates of both the `ParentComponent` as well as the `ChildComponent`. And you don't have any sort of logic that conditionally displays the `ErrorComponent` in the template of either the `ParentComponent` or the `ChildComponent`.

That being said, to make this work, you'll have to do the following:

1. From your interceptor service, send a field that determines where the error message needs to be displayed(`showOn` in the example)
2. Make the `ErrorComponent` a dumb component. Just let it accept `errors` as an `@Input`.
3. In your `ParentComponent` and `ChildComponent` inject the `NotifyService` as a dependency and subscribe to the `errorNotifications`. Since we're setting the `showOn` property from the interceptor service, the error object that these two subscriptions will receive, will also have this `showOn` property.
4. Based on this you can set a `displayError` property on the `ParentComponent` and the `ChildComponent`. You can also then use this for the `*ngIf` to conditionally display the `ErrorComponent`.

---

Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-conditionally-display-error-in-either-parent-or-child?file=src/app/app-child.component.ts) for your ref.